# webcam interfacing with stm32

Tags: embedded, usb, webcam, stm32, stm32f4discovery

I want to use the STM32F4 microcontroller to receive a video stream then stream it over ethernet with the rtsp protocol .

I need you guys to tell me wich circuit would be the best for interfacing with STM32.

Can I interface a webcam with the STM32 via the USB OTG ? (I have basic ideas about usb protocol, but the problem is that the webcam I have is not supported by linux so there is no code source for the drivers, so no Endpoint references ...)

Is it possible to define Endpoints and vendor-specific commands that trigger the bulk transfer of video ( streaming ) by debugging the usb traffic ?

Or, would you recommend another circuit that provide video stream simple to interface with the STM32 .

I know this is kind of crazy thing to do, but I'm asking how hard it's gonna be ?

Let me know what you think of this project ?

PS:
The rtsp part of the project is not the purpose of this topic .

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can't easily run linux on an STM32F4, nor is getting a USB stack running on it, and writing your own webcam driver trivial. I would recommend going with some sort of embedded camera, or moving up to a processor that can support a full linux distro running on it.

Answer (score 1):

As stbtrax mentioned the STM32F4 processor cannot really handle video processing, so your best to move to an embedded OS system such as Odroid.

Another option is to interface a camera direct to STM32F4 using DCMI and then stream theis over USB using UVC as this guy has done. You will be limited with resolution here.
https://github.com/iliasam/STM32F4_UVC_Camera

Answer (score 0):

Some RTOSes have a host-side USB stack, such as Zephyr, but as of today (2023), no UVC (USB webcam protocol) support.

Instead of USB, which is one complex protocol, what about using a raw camera sensor?

The STM32F405 has a parallel port for a camera, as well as an Ethernet interface, and DMA to pipe things through.

There are other MCUs with similar features that you could use for that purpose, and this is likely going to evolve through time.